# As tags [progressive-web-apps] e [pwa] deveriam ser sinônimas?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

As tags [progressive-web-apps](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) e [pwa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pwa) deveriam ser sinônimas?

Sugiro que [progressive-web-apps](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) seja a principal.

Comment: Não sei se ficou bom, mas criei o uso da tag e o wiki https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/pwa/info, não domino o assunto, só li por cima alguns detalhes em 3 diferentes sites, fiquem a vontade para editar.

Comment: Alguém pode sugerir?

Comment: vnbrs, infelizmente para sugerir tem que ter um certo score na tag, e pelo que notei acho que nenhum usuário comum tem o suficiente (eu acho apenas), só moderadores podem resolver isto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As tags progressive-web-apps e pwa deveriam ser sinônimas?

**Sim.**

> Sugiro que progressive-web-apps seja a principal.

**Discordo.** O mercado usa o acrônimo PWA mais frequentemente do que a versão por extenso (como é o caso de CORS, PHP, HTML, CSS, SQL, etc.)

Comment: Concordo com sua abordagem.

Comment: Só pra constar no SOen usam PWA como sendo o sinônimo, não sei se tem um bom motivo para isto. Eu pessoalmente compartilho de sua sugestão/opinião, prefiro PWA como a principal.